# how to find a an error message in angular JS using protractor?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7EOB.png)

[MyProtractorCode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/suUJ2.png)

How to find the text "VAT Number is required."?

I tried with:

```js
err = element(by.css('.invalid error-msg')).getAttribute();
expect(err.getText()).toEqual('VAT Number is invalid.');
```

```html
<em class="invalid error-msg"> 
  <div> VAT Number is required.</div>
</em>
```

Comment: <em class="invalid error-msg">
<div> VAT Number is required. </div>
</em>

Comment: is the error triggered when you start typing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were almost there, the code should be

```js
err = element(by.css('.invalid.error-msg'));
expect(err.getText()).toEqual('VAT Number is invalid.');
```

The `getAttribute()` will only the the value of an attribute, see [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getAttribute) so you need to leave it out. You only use it when you need to know for example the `href`-value of a link, or the `class` of a specific element.

In your case you want to verify the text in an element, so it should be the above syntax, see also [here](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=webdriver.WebElement.prototype.getText)

Comment: not working :( Failed: No element found using locator: By(css selector, .invalid error-msg)

Comment: @JemiArtista, sorry, I've made an error in the css selector. Because you want to narrow the selector with 2 classes in 1 element you need to "chain" them like `.invalid.error-msg`. If you do that it should work. If not, then the element is not in the page on the moment you want to validate it

Comment: still not working...Please see the attached images for better understanding. Let me inform that this is an angular 4 based application.

Comment: Problem solved. i used "function(done)" which was automatically suggested. poor me :(..btw, thank you for the cooperation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below code.

```
var EC=protractor.ExpectedConditions;
var errWebElement = element(by.css('.invalid.error-msg'));

expect(errWebElement.getText()).toEqual("VAT Number is required.");
 **OR**
expect(EC.visibilityOf(errWebElement)).toBe(true);
```

Comment: not working...please see the attached images for better understanding.

Comment: Problem solved. i used "function(done)" which was automatically suggested. poor me :(..btw, thank you for the cooperation.